# Try-Catch While loop getting stuck on No Such Element Exception

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch

```
public static ArrayList<Student> readStudentRecords(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fileName));
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    input.useDelimiter(",");
    String firstName, lastName, id, email, hashPW;
    int maxCredits = 0;
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        try {
            input.nextLine();
            firstName = input.next();
            lastName = input.next();
            id = input.next();
            email = input.next();
            hashPW = input.next();
            maxCredits = input.nextInt();
            Student student = new Student(firstName, lastName, id, email, hashPW, maxCredits);
            students.add(student);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Illegal Argument Exception");
            input.next();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("No Such Element Exception");
            input.next();
        }
    }   
    input.close();
    return students;
}
```

I am creating a program that reads a text file that lists a students first name, last name, id, email, hashed password, and max credits. Each line of the text file has a full suite of each element seperated by commas. I want the program to read the file, create a student object from each line (I have created and tested the Student class, including all getters and setters), and arrange the student objects in an array list. The program is getting looped at NoSuchElementException, and is only reading the first line of the text file, and ignoring the next 9. I'm not sure what exact format my try-catch statement should be in to ensure that it will not infinitely loop.

Comment: looks like you are processing a csv file, so you should use a csv reader library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line in your `try` block reads the available line and then throws it away:

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    try {
        input.nextLine();
        ...
```

The reason you are getting the exception is that you throw away the line you just checked is there and then continue trying to read from `input`, whether or not there is anything *after* the line you just trashed.

You should do one of these:

1. Capture that line and parse it (rather than calling `input.next()` or `input.nextInt()` in the following lines); or
2. Eliminate the call to `input.nextLine()` and hope that each line properly conforms to the layout you expect; or
3. Replace your entire `while` loop with calls to a csv parsing utility (as @Scary Wombat suggests in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

with ***[Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)*** you need to check if there is a next line with hasNextLine()
so the loop becomes

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()){
  str=sc.nextline();
//...
}
```

this code this depends on whether the input is properly formatted

You're calling **nextLine()** and it's throwing an exception when there's no line, exactly as the javadoc describes. It will never return null

Answer (score 0):

The other answers look right to me. Just to add some more that hasn't already been said:

1. When catching an exception, make sure not to swallow it (that is ignore it) by just printing out that information. If anything, you're losing information that the `e.printStackTrace()` would have exposed, that is tell you exactly on which line it's failing on.
2. The actual error that you have is because the scanner is using `,` as the delimiter, and so that means the last value will be something like `10\n` (if 10 is the max credits for a row). You could get around this by doing something like: `String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split(",");` instead of processing it word by word with the scanner.